# LINQ to SQL: Better between Left Join and Union

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, union, left-join

I want to search restaurants which may have the keyword in their name or in their products name. I am using LINQ to SQL. 
The code is:

Data context:

```
protected MyDataContext database;
```

**Option 1:**

```
var restaurants = database.tblRestaurants.ByName(keyword).Union(database.tblRestaurants.ByFood(keyword));
```

Signature of **ByName** method:

```
public static IQueryable<tblRestaurant> ByName(this IQueryable<tblRestaurant> restaurants, string name)
{
    var result = from restaurant in restaurants
                 where restaurant.BusinessName.ToUpper().Contains(name.ToUpper())
                 select restaurant;
    return result;
}
```

Signature of **ByFood** method:

```
public static IQueryable<tblRestaurant> ByFood(this IQueryable<tblRestaurant> restaurants, string food)
{
    var result = from restaurant in restaurants
                 from product in restaurant.tblProducts
                 where product.Name.ToUpper().Contains(food.ToUpper())
                 select restaurant;
    return result;
}
```

It works fine. But I have another option to select using left join.
**Option 2:**

```
    var restaurants = from restaurant in database.tblRestaurants
                      join product in database.tblProducts
                          on restaurant.OId equals product.RestaurantOId into products
                      from p in products.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where
                          p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(keyword.ToUpper()) |
                          restaurant.BusinessName.ToUpper().Contains(keyword.ToUpper())
                      select restaurant;
```

My question is, which one should I use. The consideration parameters are

- Performance
- Maintainability
- OOP

**In a summary, what would you do if you have both options**

Comment: are you sure you want to use *contains*. It looks for an exact match so it only returns true if productname == food (so for example the restaurant "APPLEBAR" wil not show up if you use contains "APPLE" ...

Comment: i am sure because i want to search for the keywords, not searching for a specific restaurant.

Comment: you are looking for "in their name"... this is not what Contains does in Linq2sql. Contains checks if an item is in the other list.

Answer (score 0):

change query in option 2 to as follows

```
from restaurant in restaurants
where restaurant..BusinessName.ToUpper().Contains(keyword.ToUpper()) 
|| restaurant.tblProducts.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(keyword.ToUpper()) ) != null
select restaurant;
```